# Update postgres array jsonb

Tags: postgresql, json

I'm using postgres 9.6, and my question is about updating a jsonb array column.

My table looks more or less like that:

```
ID Name MyArray
5  John [{"key":1,"key2":a}]
6  Mike [{"key":4,"key2":b}]
```

ID integer,Name varchar, MyArray jsonb

I would like to update the jsonb array column with new data, without overriding the existing data.

I tried the following without success:

```
UPDATE myTable SET MyArray= myArray || {"key3":4} 

UPDATE myTable SET MyArray= myArray::jsonb || {"key3":4}::jsonb
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks

Comment: Your method worked for me. What do you want exactly? Can you please share what output you want to see?

Answer (score 0):

The `||` operator works since PostgreSQL 9.5 for `jsonb` types, as described on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

Example:

```
SELECT '{"key":1, "key2": 3}'::jsonb as input,
('{"key":1, "key2": 3}'::jsonb || '{"key3":4}'::jsonb) as output;

| input              | output                      |
| ------------------ | --------------------------- |
| {"key":1,"key2":3} | {"key":1,"key2":3,"key3":4} |
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for.
I'm trying to update array with new values, not to select them

Comment: @Chenko It is trivial to extend that to an update, it was just to show you that `||` works but with jsonb. So your added update should work as is.